# TabItem for many different TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have many project in my solution.
In a lot of project i have one TabControl.
On of my project is a dll.
How to create a tabItem in dll, for adding dynamicly in TabControl of other projet ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `UserControl` in your dll, then reference it in other projects.
And showing what you tried, and where your problem is rather than asking a simple question that any search engine could answer would avoid you some downvotes.

Comment: Yes i create one UserControl, with this XAML code:
`<TabItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="450" Header="StopBot" Height="362">
    <Grid Background="White" Margin="0,-4,0,4">
        <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="46,61,-146,-161" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>`

but the viewer does not work, and I can not add items to a TabControl

Comment: Nope, that's not a `UserControl`, otherwise it'd begin with `<UserControl x:Class="yourUserControlName"`. `UserControl` is a real class ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx ), not just a way to say it's a component you made.

Comment: doesn't work with
`<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="450" Height="362">
    <Grid Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="StopBotAfter">
            <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>  
        </TabItem>       
    </Grid>
</UserControl>`

Comment: The declaration is not correct, it's not linked to your custom class. You really should have a look to the documentation (MSDN link in previous comment) and some tutos ( for example, first link on Google : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W ). Oh, and comments are **NOT** meant to post code snippets.